# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Label

Tags: c#, wpf, label

Hi am quite new to visual studios.

This is my code so far to make an example of an atm, where you the put the amount in and then click credit it adds to the balance and click debit and it takes it out. am doing this inc# wpf application.

so far i have this.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private double totalamount = 0;
    public string balance1;


    private void buttoncredit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        totalamount = totalamount + double.Parse(textboxamount.Text);

        balance1 = "Your Balance is: £";

        label2 = balance1 + totalamount;
```

and then this error comes along . "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Label"

I have done this in forms . where i say label2.text = ..... and it works . but on the wpf i can't do this. if someone can guide me it will be much appricated.

thanks .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For wpf the equivalent is:

```
label2.Content = balance1 + totalamount;
```

Comment: if you look at the code. it doesn't like the "totalamount = .... " it says Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the `Text` property of the `Label` not the `Label` itself. So try this:

**In Windows form**:

```
label2.Text = balance1 + totalamount;
```

**In WPF**:

```
label2.Content = balance1 + totalamount;
```

Comment: I have done that and this this error comes along" Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"